# How to use Apache and nodejs server together on VPS (centos)

Tags: node.js, apache, vps

I am using apache for Php as well as nodejs sokcetio for chat app. It is working fine on my Localhost. I have a bluehost vps. How can I use apache and nodejs together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run NodeJS application on port other than the default apache ports (80 and 443).

Comment: I am running node on port 3000, but it's not working on live server

Comment: You need to open 3000 port from the server's firewall.

Comment: how? and how can I run my server.js file on live server once the 3000 port is ready

Comment: If you are running a Linux server use either iptables to open 3000 port or firewalld if it is used. No need to change the node application configuration, run it on 3000 port.

Comment: If you find that the answer resolved your query, kindly mark it as the answer.

Comment: Which server are you using for the application, kindly provide the OS and firewall that you are using.

Comment: I am using buehost vps. OS Centos 6.9

Comment: Refer to this link for basic iptables functionalities.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands